# Android: Retrieve all image directories

Tags: android, media, android-image, android-file

I am trying to find all directories on an Android device that contain images (internal as well as external storage).
Basically, I try to get all the directories that are listed in the native gallery application

So for example:

- All images
- Downloads
- My Favourites
- Whatsapp Pictures
  ...

How does one accomplish this? I think it is related to MediaStorage.Images.Media and so on, but the documentation is not very helpful there and a lot of google searches didn't help as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @BlazingFire, who did not fully answer my question, but provided some code I could work with and have now my desired result:

```
public ArrayList<String> getFile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (File file : listFile) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                getFile(file);
            }
            else {
                if (file.getName().endsWith(".png")
                        || file.getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || file.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                        || file.getName().endsWith(".gif")
                        || file.getName().endsWith(".bmp")
                        || file.getName().endsWith(".webp"))
                {
                    String temp = file.getPath().substring(0, file.getPath().lastIndexOf('/'));
                    if (!fileList.contains(temp))
                        fileList.add(temp);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

It only adds parent directories of images and only if they have not yet been added. I also included .bmp and .webp as valid image file extensions

Comment: Yeah, you got what I was talking about

Comment: i am getting root file and all sub file empty ("") .

Answer (score 5):

You can use this code to find picture folders in Storage -

```
private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();    

...

public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {
        if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))
            {
                String temp = file.getPath().substring(0, file.getPath().lastIndexOf('/'));
                fileList.add(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

And then you can call the `ArrayList` this way -

```
File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
getFile(root);
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
    String stringFile = fileList.get(i).getName();
    Do whatever you want to do with each filename here...
}
```

Comment: Your code does not only add the Parent directories, but also all the filenames of every single picture on the device! BUT you still helped me a lot with your code, because I did not think it was so easy to search through all the directories!

Comment: I will use your code to make something that fits 100% to my case and post it here. I don't know if I should accept your answer now...

Comment: `You can use this code to find pictures in Storage`  does not quite seem an answer to your question `trying to find all directories on an Android device`.

Comment: Yes, that's why I won't accept it as an answer, because what I was looking for was more for all parent directories that contain images, so .../Whatsapp/, ../Camera/ and so on

Comment: @BastiSkaldendudler I don't have access to my PC now, so I'll update the answer after some time... All you need to do is remove the `image` string from the rest of the string to get the folder DIR.

Comment: How were you able to add a string to an array of Files?                 String temp = file.getPath().substring(0, file.getPath().lastIndexOf('/'));
                fileList.add(temp);

Comment: i am getting root file and all sub file empty ("") .